# Does a Bot Framework bot need to be registered every time it changes, or only once?

Tags: botframework

I have created Bot 'MyFirstBOT' where my backend is QnA maker application data. I have given a name to this bot called 'TestJPBOT' and I have enabled the Teams channel for this bot so that we can use this bot on Teams applications. Right now in our organization we are working to register this bot with Microsoft so that we can start using it. I would like to know going forward if I want to make any changes in the bot, like changing its name, profile picture, or something similar, do I need to reregister it every time with Microsoft? Or is there no need?

Comment: Please, share your code.

Answer (score 0):

Per my simple testing using Azure Bot Service env, we **don't need register again** after change our bots.

Actually, register your bot is populate your bot on Microsoft, equivalent to create a index for your bot I think. You change your bot's profile or code, should not effect the index.